# Scale DIV with tiles

Tags: tiles, html5, web

I am trying to create a repeating background. I have a main DIV with a grid of small 16x16 DIVs. I am trying to scale the main DIV in CSS; when the small DIVs simply have a red background color everything works great, but when there is a background image in the small DIVs then borders become visible between the tiles.

This image explains the problem:
http://cl.ly/FpNW/o

**Check the HTML in these examples:**

With BG-COLOR: http://jsfiddle.net/pTLXw/

With BG-IMG: http://jsfiddle.net/vkpuY/

Does anyone know what is causing this problem and how to fix it? If it is not possible to fix while using DIV, is there another way to do this?

Thanks you so much!

Comment: Does it happen with 1.375 instead of 1.4, too?

Comment: With 1.375 works great on webkit, but not in Firefox. Check: http://jsfiddle.net/vkpuY/2/ (Why 1.375? Thanks!)

Comment: I've edited your question to have the text of your question. Explain your problem/question in the posts you make here, not hidden behind a link.

Comment: I assume you did set the borders to 0, yes?

Comment: Incidentally, this question isn't about game development, so I'm voting to migrate this to StackOverflow.

Comment: @Everu I suppose the browser can only display stuff at integer coordinates. If they resize a 16×16 image, since 16 * 1.4 is 22.4, which is not an integer, there will be inaccuracies. However 16 × 1.375 = 22 which is an integer, so it has better chances to work well.

Answer (score 1):

It's a result of the different scaling methods used by the different browsers. I'd generally stay away from using that scaling, but if you want your current problem solved, have the tiles overlap slightly.